# How do I increment to a certain limit that I can define?

Tags: swift, class, limit, increment

I'm working on creating classes and methods and in one of them, I'm looking to increase one variable but not beyond the input of the other variable.

```
class Vehicle{
   let name: String
   let weight: Double
   let maxSpeed: Double
   var speed: Double = 0
   var heading: Double = 0

init(name: String, weight: Double, maxSpeed: Double) {
    self.name = name
    self.weight = weight
    self.maxSpeed = maxSpeed
}

func accelerate() {
    speed += maxSpeed/10
}
```

In the method, I'm incrementing the speed by 1/10th of the maxSpeed but I don't want speed in the accelerate method to exceed the maxSpeed (since that wouldn't make much sense). Is there any way to set a range on how high/low speed could go?

Comment: Use the magic word `if`. Like, `if speed + maxSpeed/10 <= maxSpeed {speed += maxSpeed/10}`.

Comment: Use what  @matt said. Seems like this would be something you'd learn near the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to do this, depending on how strictly you want to enforce your requirement.

If you want to `speed` to only increase via the `accelerate()` method, you can put in a check:

```
func accelerate() {
    speed = min(speed + maxSpeed/10, maxSpeed)
}
```

This doesn't prevent user from changing `speed` via the property:

```
myVehicle.speed = 10000
myVehicle.speed += 10
```

So you may want to hide the setter for `speed`:

```
private(set) var speed: Double
```

Even then, other methods in your class may unintentionally set it over the limit. You have to put the check everywhere.

---

If you want it to be always below `maxSpeed` no matter how you change it, use a property observer:

```
class Vehicle {

    var speed: Double {
        didSet {
            speed = min(speed, maxSpeed)
        } 
    }
 }

let truck = Vehicle(name: "Ford F150", weight: 3000, maxSpeed: 200)
truck.speed = 300
print(truck.speed) // limited to 200

truck.accelerate()
print(truck.speed) // still 200
```

Answer (score 0):

You are asking to *clamp* the value of `speed`. The Swifty way to do that is to use a *setter observer*:

```
var speed : Double {
    didSet(oldSpeed) {
        if speed > maxSpeed {
            speed = oldSpeed 
        }
    }
}
```